# Julia llvm function signature when using arrays

Tags: llvm, julia, llvm-ir

When looking at the LLVM IR that the julia compiler generates (using `code_llvm`) I noticed something strange in the function signature when using arrays as arguments. Let me give an example:

```
function test(a,b,c)
    return nothing
end
```

(This is a useless example, but the results are the same with other functions, the resulting IR of this example is just less cluttered)

Using `code_llvm(test, (Int,Int,Int))`, I get the following output:

```
; Function Attrs: sspreq
define void @julia_test14855(i64, i64, i64) #2 {
top:
  ret void, !dbg !366
}
```

Using `code_llvm(test, (Array{Int},Array{Int},Array{Int}))`, I get an (at least for me) unexpected result:

```
; Function Attrs: sspreq
define %jl_value_t* @julia_test14856(%jl_value_t*, %jl_value_t**, i32) #2 {
top:
  %3 = icmp eq i32 %2, 3, !dbg !369
  br i1 %3, label %ifcont, label %else, !dbg !369

else:                                             ; preds = %top
  call void @jl_error(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([26 x i8]* @_j_str0, i64 0, i64 0)), !dbg !369
  unreachable, !dbg !369

ifcont:                                           ; preds = %top
  %4 = load %jl_value_t** inttoptr (i64 36005472 to %jl_value_t**), align 32, !dbg !370
  ret %jl_value_t* %4, !dbg !370
}
```

Why is the signature of the llvm function not just listing the 3 variables as `i64*` or something like that? And why doesn't the function return `void` anymore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Why is the signature of the llvm function not just listing the 3 variables as i64*`

This signature is the generic Julia calling convention (because, as @ivarne mentioned, the types are incomplete).

`@julia_test14856(%jl_value_t*, %jl_value_t**, i32)` arguments are:

1. pointer to the function closure
2. pointers to boxed arguments (jl_value_t is basic box type)
3. number of arguments

The signature @ivarne shows is the specialized calling convention. Arguments are still passed boxed, but argument type and count are known already (and the function closure is unnecessary because it is already specialized).

About the output of your example function, this section checks the number of arguments (if not 3 -> goto label `else:`):

```
top:
  %3 = icmp eq i32 %2, 3, !dbg !369
  br i1 %3, label %ifcont, label %else, !dbg !369
```

This section returns the error:

```
else:                                             ; preds = %top
  call void @jl_error(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([26 x i8]* @_j_str0, i64 0, i64 0)), !dbg !369
  unreachable, !dbg !369
```

Finally, the default case goes to this line which pulls the value for `nothing` stored in address `36005472` (in @ivarne version, this is guaranteed, so can return `void` directly).

`%4 = load %jl_value_t** inttoptr (i64 36005472 to %jl_value_t**), align 32, !dbg !370`

Comment: Thanks. Nice to see that my intuition lead me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

I would assume that it is because `Array{Int, N}` is a partially initialized type, and that it does not match the patterns the code generation looks for.

Try also

```
julia> code_llvm(test, (Array{Int,1},Array{Int,1},Array{Int,1}))

define void @julia_test15626(%jl_value_t*, %jl_value_t*, %jl_value_t*) {
top:
  ret void, !dbg !974
}
```

This might be considered a bug in the code generation, but I do not know.